# Copy styled text from a JTextPane to Microsoft Word

Tags: java, html, swing, ms-word, clipboard

I want to copy styled text from a JTextPane to Microsoft Word. I already use this code, and it works, but it gets wrong with the accents:

```
    Clipboard clp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    ByteArrayOutputStream ot = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    RTFEditorKit kit = new RTFEditorKit();
    try {
        kit.write(ot, jTextPane1.getDocument(), 0, jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength());
        ot.flush();
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(ot.toByteArray(), kit.getContentType());
        clp.setContents(dh, null);
    } catch (IOException | BadLocationException e1) {

    }
```

When I paste something like café to Microsoft Word, it looks like this: CafÈ .  And with the other it would be:  áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ   ->  ·ÈÌÛ˙ ¡…Õ”⁄

The text in the JTextPane is html.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft word understands unicode. Your code is using ascii text.

See here for the difference - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/all-
about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/

Another issue may be the null termination. In your case, the issue seems to be the `ot.toByteArray` - a byte array will be fine for 8-bit ascii. Unicode uses
a 16-bit short for storage.